# Why Isnt This Function Consuming Lazily?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I have two functions similar to `filter` and `takeWhile`.

```
filterAcc, takeWhileAcc :: ([a] -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterAcc p xs = go xs []
    where go [] acc     = acc
          go (x:xs) acc
            | p (x:acc) = go xs (x:acc)
            | otherwise = go xs acc

takeWhileAcc p xs = go xs []
    where go [] acc     = acc
          go (x:xs) acc
            | p (x:acc) = go xs (x:acc)
            | otherwise = acc
```

they both take predicates and lists, and they differ from the regular `filter` and `takeWhile` in that the predicates take the accumulated result as inputs.

my problem is that while `filter even [1..]` will start producing output immediately (lazily), `filterAcc (any even) [1..]` hangs. My suspicion is that the helper function `go` is preventing these functions from acting lazily.

How can i make these functions operate lazily?

Comment: Note that it is completely pointless - and counter-productive - to pass the accumulators as arguments to `go` if it produces lazily. Accumulators are for incrementally computed results that can not be delivered incrementally. If you can deliver the result incrementally, the only reason to keep a reference to the already delivered part would be if that is needed for the [efficient] computation of the remaining part.

Comment: @DanielFischer: it struck me that there might be a better way to implement these functions. I asked around on #haskell, but didnt get an answer. Can you suggest a better method? I was thinking it might be possible in the State monad, but I'm not very used to using the State monad yet.

Comment: Oh, sorry, haven't read properly (was before the first cup of tea). You actually need the accumulated results for the test, so the last part of the last sentence applies.

Comment: However, you accumulate in reverse order of appearance in the original list, while incremental output necessarily comes (more or less) in the order of appearance. What are the intended semantics? Does the result of the test depend on whether its argument list is in original order or reversed?

Comment: in my particular case, the predicates dont care what order the accumulated list is in. The functions should produce output in the same order as the input list, so for my uses the solution hammar provided is perfect.

Comment: In that case, hammar's solution is the best indeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the cons case of `go` always ends in a tail call to itself. It only returns something useful when it's reached the end of the list, which of course never happens with an infinite list.

Instead, you should return elements as you go:

```
filterAcc, takeWhileAcc :: ([a] -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterAcc p xs = go xs []
    where go [] acc     = []
          go (x:xs) acc
            | p (x:acc) = x : go xs (x:acc)
            | otherwise = go xs acc

takeWhileAcc p xs = go xs []
    where go [] acc     = []
          go (x:xs) acc
            | p (x:acc) = x : go xs (x:acc)
            | otherwise = []
```

Answer (score 1):

Lazy list consumption is usually achieved by `foldr`.

You need left-to-right information flow for your accumulator. This is usually achieved by using `foldl`, but that means strict list consumption.

The solution is to use `scanl`:

```
--- mapAccumL :: (acc -> x -> (acc, y)) -> acc -> [x] -> (acc, [y])
--- scanl     :: (a   -> b -> a)        -> a   -> [b] -> [a]

takeWhileAcc p []     = []
takeWhileAcc p (x:xs) = map snd $ takeWhile (p.fst) 
                                $ scanl (\(acc,_) y-> (y:acc,y)) ([x],x) xs

filterAcc p []        = []
filterAcc p (x:xs)    = map snd $ filter (p.fst) 
                                $ scanl (\(acc,_) y-> (y:acc,y)) ([x],x) xs
```

Another possibility is to use `until`, or `mapAccumL`. The latter would be a natural fit, except that it doesn't collect the accumulated values, but rather passes along the last accumulator value.